# Order by urgency in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

In a DataGridView, when a user clicks on a column header, it automatically orders them alphabetically or numerically. However, I was wondering if there was a way to make a column order itself by something like date or "urgency"?

Unfortunately I have no idea of where to get started with this, so any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you load your datagridview ¿?.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla Dynamically. It's not linked to any data sources

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0868ft3z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Can you pls add that piece of code.

Comment: @Juan I don't want it to be populated that by ascending/descending "Urgency" or anything like that, I want to be able to re-order the rows when I click on the column header.

Answer (score 1):

A DataGridView should be able to sort a date column, or more specifically a column of DateTime values, out of the box. Just be sure that the [SortMode property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.sortmode(v=vs.110).aspx) is Automatic for the column, and that the type of the corresponding field in the datasource is DateTime.

As far as sorting by "urgency," I'm not exactly sure what you mean there, but it sounds like a custom sort. For that, handle the click event on the column header and use the Sort method with an implementation of IComparer that contains your custom urgency sort logic. More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wstxtkxs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: This does look promising, and to clarify when I say "Urgency", yeah, it pretty much is a custom sort. I'm looking to sort between a selection of strings like `Not Important`, `Low Priority`, `High Priority` and `Urgent`.